# document.getElemenyById not working in one file but working in other

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

this function is running in one of my files but not working in other one, i have checked all the names etc but couldn't find.....

in first file

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function fillDataInCommand()
    {
//      var abc = document.myApp.getDataForCommand();
    var abc ="heelo syed ammar hassan is here";
        document.getElementById("commandtextarea").value = abc;
    }

</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
  <textarea name="commandtextarea" style="background-color:#CCCCCC" cols="80" rows="20" wrap="off" id="commandtextarea"></textarea>
  </label>
</form>
```

and in other one;

```
document.write ("<div align='center'><textarea name='commandtextarea' style='background-color:#EFEFEF' cols ='70' rows='20' rap='off' id='commandtextarea' readonly='readonly'>abc</textarea></div>");

alert(document.getElementById("commandtextarea").value.toString());
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It's very difficult to help you without actual code

Answer (score 7):

It is because of the document.write function. After that you won't have a textbox in the document and so document.getElementById fails.

document.write statements must be run before the page finishes loading. This means that they must be either in the body of the page or in functions called from the body of the page.

> Any document.write statement that runs
>   after the page finishes loading will
>   create a new page and overwrite all of
>   the content of the current page.

Comment: +1, document.write misunderstandings cause a lot of confusion. Squirt your html into an element using document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = "<p>My HTML</p>";

Answer (score 0):

You're using `document.getElementByName` in the second file. You mean to be using `document.getElementById`.

EDIT: you were, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try alert(document.getElementByName("commandtextarea").value alone.